# Populating description of revision from LookBackAPI

Tags: rally

I am trying to come up with something similar to the "Revisions" tab for a user story. I have everything I need but the description.

Should I be able to take the revision number or ID and search the "Revision History" residing in the story?

I wasn't sure if the revision contents would be time sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example.
Following this in order to gain revision history.

https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/last-revision-of-recently-updated-artifacts